# Replace view inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipickerview, uistackview, xcode-storyboard

I have a `UIStackView` with 5 buttons inside. One of those buttons (**#4**) needs to be replaced by a `UIPickerView` once it is clicked and switched back to the `UIButton` once one of the other four's is selected.

The `UIStackView` is **horizontal**, alignment is **fill** and distribution is **Fill Proportionally**.

The stack was done using **storyboard**, and I am trying to replace the view with:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        self.pickerView.frame.origin = self.view.viewWithTag(40)!.frame.origin
        self.pickerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)

}
```

But my `UIStackView` will not rearrange after the button click, and button **#5** is staying on top of the `UIPickerView`.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to change the content after the button is pressed then do it in the target / selector of the button. You need remove arranged sub view and insert arranged sub view to stack view. Don’t hard code frame / size. Please read the UIStackView documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the code. I had to replace `addView` for `addArrangedSubview`.

Final code (on button press):

```
    let stack = (self.view.viewWithTag(20) as! UIStackView)
    stack.addArrangedSubview(self.pickerView)
```